# Android AutoCompleteTextView reset previous selected value

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I am having a hard time trying to get one of my AutoCompleteTextView to reset based on a selection from another AutoCompleteTextView selection.

Below are the form elements:

The first one is the dropdown for `Sport Type`:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/sportType"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:hint="Select Sport"
    android:labelFor="@+id/sportTypeSelected"
    android:background="#EAE7E7">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/sportTypeSelected"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

followed by the second on that is `Pool Type`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/poolType"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:hint="Select Pool Type"
    android:labelFor="@+id/poolTypeSelected"
    android:background="#EAE7E7">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/poolTypeSelected"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Here is the Java code that does the work to get the drop down populated:

This is for the `Sport Type`

So what is happening is the `Sport Type` drop down will populate on creation of the view:

```
sportTypeSelected = findViewById(R.id.sportTypeSelected);
    
List<String> sportsTypes = new ArrayList<>();

sportTypeListener = sportsTypesReference.orderByValue().equalTo("A").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

            sportsTypes.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot sportSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String sportType = sportSnapshot.getKey();

                sportsTypes.add(sportType);

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

});

numSportsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, sportsTypes);
    
sportTypeSelected.setAdapter(numSportsAdapter);
```

For the `Pool Type`, is not preloaded based on the hiding of the drop down.

Then based on the selection of the `Sport Type`, the `setOnItemClickListener` will trigger the `Pool Type` to populate

```
poolTypeSelected = findViewById(R.id.poolTypeSelected);
    
List<String> poolTypes = new ArrayList<>();

// HIDE THE DROPDOWN
poolTypeSelected.setDropDownHeight(0); <-- Hide the drop down init
poolTypeSelected.setDropDownWidth(0); <-- Hide the drop down init


sportTypeSelected.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // Enable
        poolTypeSelected.setDropDownHeight(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        poolTypeSelected.setDropDownWidth(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        poolTypeListener = poolTypesReference.child(sportTypeSelected.getText().toString()).orderByValue().equalTo("A").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    poolTypes.clear();

                    for (DataSnapshot sportSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        String pTypes = sportSnapshot.getKey();

                        poolTypes.add(pTypes);

                    }

                } 

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });

    }

});

numPoolsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, poolTypes);

poolTypeSelected.setAdapter(numPoolsAdapter);
```

My issue is that I would like for the `Pool Type` to get `blanked out/reset` every time the selection changes in the `Sport Type` dropdown as the choices could change.

Can someone please let me know how I can achieve this!?

---

Update:
If I use:

```
poolTypeSelected.setText("");
```

the rest of my Firebase lookup wont populate and I land up with a blank dropdown.

I'll assume that its a timing issue and the `setText("")` is removing the entires retrieved by the Firebase lookup.

Comment: hi, perhaps might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472317/change-values-in-2nd-dropdown-based-on-another-dropdown-android

Comment: @jspcal so mine is different, as its getting the data from Firebase. Also my code works as desired.... EXCEPT that when a user makes a selection in the `Pool Type` and then goes back to modify the `Sport Type` the entry in the `Pool Type` doesnt `reset` to `blank for null` etc... looking for some help with that.